# Unbalanced dollar signs

Tags: macros, parsing, token-lists

I'm curious: why do the following two examples behave differently?

Example 1: (Works, displays xyz in displaymath mode.)

```latex
\newcommand\weird{$$xyz$}
\weird$
```

Example 2: (Error, missing $ inserted.)

```latex
\newcommand\curious{$uvw$$}
$\curious
```

Same phenomena if I replace `\newcommand` by `\def`.

What's going on under the hood?

Comment: For the sake of having fun try: `\expandafter$\curious`   ;-)

Comment: Note that if you actually want to distinguish between opening and closing inline and display math delimiters, you can use `\(`, `\[`, etc.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First example:

```
\newcommand\weird{$$xyz$}
\weird$
```

- `\weird` is expanded to `$$xyz$` and processed;
- The first `$` is identified and TeX searches for a following `$` since there's a difference in how `$`...`$` and `$$`...`$$` are set;
- TeX find a subsequent `$`, thereby initiating a display math equation;
- After processing the equation interior, it searches for a closing `$$`;
- TeX finds `$` (part of `\weird`) and, like before, searches for a subsequent `$`;
- TeX finds the closing `$` (outside of `\weird`) and closes off the display math equation.

Using a more LaTeX-like coding, the interpretation of the expansion resembles

```
\[xyz\]
```

---

Second example:

```
\newcommand\curious{$uvw$$}
$\curious
```

- TeX find `$` and looks for a following `$` since there's a difference in how `$`...`$` and `$$`...`$$` are set;
- There is no subsequent `$` (actually, the next token is `\curious`), so TeX opens a regular inline math expression;
- TeX expands `\curious` to `$uvw$$`;
- TeX find `$` (inside `\curious`) and closes the inline math expression;
- TeX processes `uvw`;
- TeX find `$` and looks for a following `$` since there's a difference in how `$`...`$` and `$$`...`$$` are set;
- TeX finds a subsequent `$` and opens a display math expression;
- No closing `$$` is found - error.

Using a more LaTeX-like coding, the interpretation of the expansion resembles

```
\(\)xyz\[
```

Answer (score 13):

As explained in chapter 24 of the TeXbook, a (category code 3) `$` cannot be in vertical mode: if it is found when TeX is in vertical mode, horizontal mode is started and `$` is reexamined.

Chapter 25 specifies

> • `$`. A “math shift” character causes TeX to enter math mode or display math mode in the following way: TeX looks at the following token without expanding it. If that token is a `$` and if TeX is currently in unrestricted horizontal mode, then TeX breaks the current paragraph […]. Otherwise TeX puts the looked-at token back into the input, enters a new level of grouping, inserts the `\everymath` tokens, and processes ‘⟨math mode material⟩`$`[…].’

The clause *without expanding it* is the key to understanding what you found out.

With `\weird$`, TeX expands `\weird` and so it sees `$$weird$$`.

With `$\curious`, the token following `$` is *not* `$`, so TeX starts inline math mode and only after that (and after having inserted the `\everymath` tokens) it expands `\curious`, which leaves `$curious$$` in the input stream. The first `$` ends the just started math mode and `$$` will start display math mode.

However, neither `\hbox{\weird$}` nor `\hbox{$\curious$}` would raise errors, but in this case `xyz` and `uvw` would be in text mode. Why is that? The “if TeX is currently in unrestricted horizontal mode” clause enters action: inside `\hbox`, TeX is in *restricted* horizontal mode: the rules stated above imply that in restricted horizontal mode `$$` is just an empty math formula.

Answer (score 0):

All commands in latex start with . Any sign before that becomes  a part of text. $ sign in the beginning indicates that it is a maths symbol.